# почему выдает None

Tags: python, парсер

при парсинге страници яндекс погожды None
вот мой код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://yandex.ru/pogoda/?lat=55.035748113910586&lon=82.92160002700581"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')
result = soup.find("h1", { "id" : "main_title" })
print (result) # None
```

Comment: Потому что ничего не находит  Неужели сложно сообразить?..

Comment: Ознакомтесь https://yandex.ru/dev/weather/?utm_content=header__business_solutions&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=yandex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Яндекс блокирует автоматизированные запросы, поэтому данные которые вы запрашиваете отсутствуют. В этом можно убедиться:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://yandex.ru/pogoda/?lat=55.035748113910586&lon=82.92160002700581"
request = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find("span", {'class': 'Text_weight_regular'})

print(result.contents[0])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Чтобы получить нужные данные, требуется обойти капчу.